# Limit the local of this email verification RegEX to 64 or less characthers

Tags: regex, email

The following does work but limits the entire email string to less than 64 characters.
What I want to do is to limit the local part of the email... in other words, the string before the @domain.whatevs, to 64 characters or less.

This is what I have:
`/^(?=^.{1,65}$)(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))|` `@(([^_<>()\.,;\s@\"]+\.{0,1})+[^<>()\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/g`

The issue is definitely in here: `(?=^.{1,65}$)`.... just not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to check if the pattern start with 1-64 characters, where the characters are not any of a whitespace char or @, then followed by matching an @

Then rest of the pattern after the @ sign you can specify what you want to allow to match.

In this example, it can not match any @, and should contain a dot followed by 1+ times any char except a `.` `@` or whitespace char.

```
^(?=[^\s@]{1,64}@)[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@.]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/apCIFi/1)